# Database information from txt using pdo class

Tags: pdo, sqlsrv

I am new on pdo and classes. I use this code to connect to database if i write the database information manually. But i want to read all these information from text file which has 4 lines. I use this code below but something is wrong.

```
$sqlsrv_txt = "evrak_tip.txt";
$satirlar = file($sqlsrv_txt);
$host = substr($satirlar[0], strpos($satirlar[0], ":") + 1);
$db_name = substr($satirlar[1], strpos($satirlar[1], ":") + 1);
$username = substr($satirlar[2], strpos($satirlar[2], ":") + 1);
$password = substr($satirlar[3], strpos($satirlar[3], ":") + 1);

class Database
{

    private $host = "HOST NAME";
    private $db_name = "DB NAME";
    private $username = "USER NAME";
    private $password = "PASSWORD";
    public $conn;

public function dbConnection()
{

    $this->conn = null;    
    try
    {
        $this->conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=" . $this->host . ";Database=" 
 .$this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, 
PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8); 
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $this->conn;
  }
}
```

As you can see in the code, i need to write host,db_name,username and password accoridng to variables coming from txt file.

Can anybody help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by creating and reading ini file.

```
$config = parse_ini_file("config.ini");
$this->conn = new 
PDO($config['type'].":server=".$config['host'].";Database=".$config['dbname'], 
$config['user'], $config['password']);
```